# How to automatically start your service after install?

Tags: .net, installation, service

How do you automatically start a service after running an install from a Visual Studio Setup Project?

I just figured this one out and thought I would share the answer for the general good.  Answer to follow.  I am open to other and better ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm so glad to see someone posting a useful question for which they know the answer. Sometimes you just know your tip will be welcome. It's also possible that someone will reply with an attractive alternative to your solution.

Comment: That is exactly what I am hoping for.

Comment: That is such an obvious thing to want to do. It never ceases to amaze me the things Microsoft leave out of their code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add the following class to your project.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;  

class ServInstaller : ServiceInstaller
{
    protected override void OnCommitted(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("YourServiceNameGoesHere");
        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

The Setup Project will pick up the class and run your service after the installer finishes.

Comment: ServiceController implements IDisposable.  Was not using the 'using' keyword or calling the Dispose method intentional?

Comment: I agree it is always a good idea to dispose properly.  In this instance, it only runs once.  The OnCommitted fires after the installation program runs and then the service is managed like any other and automatically starts on the next reboot.

Comment: What about base.OnCommitted(...). Does that need to be called?

Comment: Instead of creating a new class, you can just use either the Committed or AfterInstall event. See answers below.

Answer (score 41):

Small addition to accepted answer:

You can also fetch the service name like this - avoiding any problems if service name is changed in the future:

```
protected override void OnCommitted(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName).Start();
}
```

(Every Installer has a ServiceProcessInstaller and a ServiceInstaller. Here the ServiceInstaller is called serviceInstaller1.)

Comment: serviceInstaller1 is a private member variable of ProjectInstaller so how do I go about accessing it from ServInstaller ?

Answer (score 25):

This approach uses the Installer class and the least amount of code.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace MyProject
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serviceInstaller1.AfterInstall += (sender, args) => new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Define `serviceInstaller1` (type ServiceInstaller) in the Installer class designer and also set its `ServiceName` property in the designer.

Comment: I have to put this code in the Committed event instead. Seems like my service is not available OnAfterInstall yet.

Answer (score 9):

thanks it run OK...

```
private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;

private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("YourServiceName");
    sc.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is actually the simplest way since Service installer and AfterInstall event is already there - no need to add new class.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating your own class, select the service installer in the project installer and add an event handler to the Comitted event:

```
private void serviceInstallerService1_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    var serviceInstaller = sender as ServiceInstaller;
    // Start the service after it is installed.
    if (serviceInstaller != null && serviceInstaller.StartType == ServiceStartMode.Automatic)
    {
        var serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName);
        serviceController.Start();
    }
}
```

It will start your service only if startup type is set to automatic.

Comment: Don't forget to add: `using System.ServiceProcess;`

Comment: this is the option that worked the best for me and seems the simplest and most obvious

Answer (score 3):

Based on the snippets above, my ProjectInstaller.cs file wound up looking like this for a service named FSWServiceMgr.exe. The service did start after installation. As a side note, remember to click on the Properties tab (not right-click) when the setup project is selected in the Solution Explorer to set the company and so forth.

---

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace FSWManager {
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer {
        public ProjectInstaller() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FSWServiceMgr.AfterInstall += FSWServiceMgr_AfterInstall;
        }

        static void FSWServiceMgr_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e) {
            new ServiceController("FSWServiceMgr").Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way which does not involve code. You can use the Service Control Table. Edit the generated msi file with orca.exe, and add an entry to the [ServiceControl Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371634(v=vs.85).aspx).

Only the ServiceControl, Name,Event and Component_ columns are mandatory. The Component_ column contains the ComponentId from the File Table. (Select the File in the file table, and copy the Component_value to the ServiceControl table.)

The last step is to update the value of StartServices to 6575 in table InstallExecutesequence. This is sufficient to start the service.

By the way, the service install table allows you to configure the installer to install the windows service.

Comment: Red flag! All nice and dandy and probably nice to dive into msi packages for learning and stuff but this will become a burden when publishing updates because you'll have to do all this manually each time you generate the msi package. Someone is gonna forget this at some point and it'll be forgotten all about if you don't push updates for a little while.