# Reinstall/Upgrade Windows Services using Visual Studio-integrated Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services, installation, upgrade

What (potentially free) installer software can I use that integrates with Visual Studio, so that I can install a new version of a Windows Service over an existing one. If at all possible, I'd like the installer to be able to stop the old service, remove the old service, install the new version (or just upgrade in-place), and then start the service again. Right now we're using a Visual Studio Deployment Project that creates an MSI, but that won't replace/upgrade a Windows service, nor can it start and stop the service for us.

The services are on a remote computer, so nothing can be done on the local development machine.

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at [Upgrade a Windows Service without Uninstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/327895/119477)

the accepted answer recommends using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll take a look at it. If nothing else, we'll just end up using some enterprise installer like InstallShield, since that'll do what we need ultimately. Thanks.