# Auto Start Windows Services through Installer in VS.Net 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, installation, setup-deployment

I have installed Windows Services using Setup and Deployment Wizard. I have successfully installed Services  with the help of  link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

.But when I go to services(Services.msc) I see that services **status** is not available(blank).It needs to be Started.Rather it should autmoatically start as above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212734/how-to-automatically-start-your-service-after-install

Comment: I have Followed the given in the comment, but my service doesn't automatically start after a reboot.